# The setting about setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
const enemies = [];
var A = 5;
enemies.push({
      r: Math.random() * 200+A ,
      deg: Math.random() * 360,
      opacity: 0
  });
enemies.push({
      r: Math.random() * 200 ,
      deg: Math.random() * 360,
      opacity: 0
  });
setTimeout(function() {
   A = A+50
}, 5000);
```

Excuse me guys.
I am new for JS.
Can someone tell me why my setTimeout() didn't work.
I think I lost a function to feedback for array.
What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean `didn't work`? What you were expecting it should do? What did it do instead?

Comment: Not sure what the enemies variable does in the example? But the setTimeout function seems to work. After 5 seconds A=55 instead of 5. What was the behavior you expected? Or what goes wrong?

Comment: I use canvas to draw location, I think after 5 second ,The enemies will move, but it didn't move.

Comment: Are you expecting the line `r: Math.random() * 200+A` to automatically update whenever `A` changes? If so, then this is your problem. The `+A` will simply evaluate `A` to `5` once, it won't re-evaluate `A` to `55` after 5 seconds have passed.